Is it unsafe to cook over yew firewood?
I'm aware roughly of the toxicity of yew. But I can't find definitive evidence of whether or not burning yew logs as firewood, and cooking over the yew, would cause toxic effects. I've found some analysis such as https://www.kew.org/read-and-watch/analysis-of-yew-wood that talk about the presence of taxine alkaloids and their varying amounts in the leaves, bark, and even the heartwood, so I'm certainly convinced that I should not eat out of anything yew, or use yew as a utensil, etc. But I'm curious if the flame would cause problems -- first, simply from burning (I think not, as several firewood resources mention it is a good firewood type), and second, from having something cook over a yew flame.
Of course, the general rule here would be to avoid. But I'm curious if anyone has a definitive answer!

@clvrmnky Sounds like the start of an answer...

Never mind eating the food – you are breathing the burning wood's toxic fumes.

Only tangentially related to the question, but too interesting to ignore (IMO).  A very early drug against breast and ovarian cancer, (Taxol)  was derived from the bark of the Pacific yew tree.  These trees grow slowly, and there was concern that the tree might be endangered by the demand for the drug derived from its bark.  However, synthetic drugs related to Taxol were developed in fairly short order.  See Pacific Yew, breast cancer
